# Is there a way to check that LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES are integrate successfully in android application?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using native C++ libraries in my Android application.  I am not getting any compilation error; I am able to built apk, but after installation of apk while I am running application, it is crashing.

Is there any way to check weather libraries are integrated properly or not, or is there any way that I will push all library inside Android default library folder so my app will take library from there?

I am new to Android.

Comment: please put your log and code that i well help you.

Comment: Logs are already there but in that log i am not getting any error related that library

Comment: You haven't shown us any logs. Since you say that the app is crashing, there should be a stacktrace.

Comment: i am using third party libraries so when i am using that library in my android code function. In logs files we can see that function is crashed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you will get .so file missing message in logcat but still you want to confirm in that case:

1. If you have source of that .so then put prints or dump a file using fopen and build it again . Then integrate newly build files in Android and check that then file you was dumping or prints you have put you are getting properly.
2. If you have not source of .so files
   In this case you can do using ndk-depend command just check dependencies of all so file if all depended so files are present either in libs folder of your project or in ndk then it is integrated properly.